# How do you convert a String into a Boolean in ActionScript?

Tags: string, apache-flex, actionscript, boolean, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
var bool:String = "true";
```

**Without** an if block or switch statement, how can this be converted into a Boolean object?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head how to convert that into a Boolean object, but note that you don't necessarily *need* that to be a Boolean object. It all depends on how "false" is defined; if you can set it to a null string for "false" then you can simply say if(bool){whatever;} just like a Boolean object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use:

```
var boolString:String = "true";
var boolValue:Boolean = boolString == "true"; // true
var boolString2:String = "false";
var boolValue2:Boolean = boolString2 == "true"; // false
```

---

**Edit**

A comment below suggests using

```
var boolValue:Boolean = (boolString == "true") ? true : false;
```

This is just complicating the code for no reason as the evaluation happens in the part:

```
(boolString == "true")
```

Using the ternary operator is equivalent to:

```
var tempValue:Boolean = boolString == "true"; // returns true: this is what I suggested
var boolValue:Boolean = tempValue ? true : false; // this is redundant
```

Comment: @Marcx putting an emoticon doesn't make you right. sch is right, you aren't.

Comment: I don't think, his reply is not correct... boolValue2 should be ` `false` according to his example, but in realty it is `true`...

Comment: @Marcx - I tested the code before posting it and `boolValue2` is `false` as expected.