# which way is good to check the object variable holding boolean value in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

```
        var myString:Object = "true";
        if (myString.toLowerCase() == "true")
```

**or**

```
        if (myString is Boolean)
```

**or**

```
        if (myString == Boolean)
```

Which one is good to check the object variable is holding boolean values (true or false). Or which one is right?

Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a String into a Boolean in ActionScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788234/how-do-you-convert-a-string-into-a-boolean-in-actionscript)

Comment: no.. I don't want to convert.... I just want to know the above checking conditions are right or not... and which one is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer is :**

the first instruction : `if (myString.toLowerCase() == "true")`.

---

**The long answer is :**

still the first instruction : `if (myString.toLowerCase() == "true")`.

because you are really checking if your string is equals to `"true"`, while in the 2nd instruction you are checking if your string is a `Boolean`, and in the 3rd one your checking if your string is the `Boolean` class.

Hope that can help.

Comment: yes... I understand.... If the variable is object means? Please check my edited question...

Comment: @user Your code is (was) fine. What you mean exactly ?

Comment: In your Question edit from changing `mystring` type from `String` to `Object` does not change the correctness of @akmozo answer. The only correct test is the toLowerCase test, unless you perform a Boolean conversion of the string's content to an AS3/ABC static (primate) type first, which I have to deal with in PlayScript's optimization of ActionScript dynamic objects to static CLR types (PlayScript is an AS3 to CIL Mono-based compiler)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your example code doesn't make much sense: you have an `Object` variable, yet you assume it is a `String` by using `toLowerCase()`, yet you check if it's a `Boolean`, too. If you know it's a string, make your variable a `String`:

```
var myString:String = "true";
```

If you don't know it's a string, you need to check if it's a string, or else you will get an error when if it's not a string:

```
if (myObject is String && (myObject as String).toLowerCase() == "true")
```

If it could be a boolean, you should check it as a boolean, too:

```
else if(myObject is Boolean && (myObject as Boolean) == true)
```

In general, you would be much better off having some kind of decoding process somewhere before this code so that you know what kind of data you are dealing with, and comparisons are straight forward. For example, `JSON.parse()` of a JSON data structure will result in actual boolean values for boolean, and you can decode it into typed objects with properties of type `Boolean`. The example code you have here is very fragile.

Good luck.